# How much attention should I pay to page-load metrics?

Tags: performance, metrics

My site scores a `D` in YSlow. How important is it that I get it up to say a `B` or an `A`?

I feel the page already loads quickly. I tested it at home on a modest 512k connection and it loaded in an acceptable time and was quick to browse etc. But according to YSlow there's heaps of room for improvement?

Is it worth it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it depends on what type of site you are running. If it is a person site and you don't care about how many people are visiting it then I would say don't worry about it. If it is a business and you want to give people the best experience you can then I would say worry about it some. A D in YSlow is pretty low and you probably have some reasonably easy things that can be corrected with a little work. Even though it seems fast over a 512k connection there are all kinds of things that can make it seem faster for you than it is for a lot of others. Things like compression are easy to turn on and can help a lot. You should post your score and what type of web server you are using so that people can give more specific advice.

Comment: Would if I could, I had this problem a few months ago and I've actually fixed all the issues now (up to a score of B). Sales went up by 30% when I did so I'm guessing it was worth it ;)